# Efficient way to read data from Excel using OpenXML SDK

Tags: excel, import, openxml-sdk

I am trying to import data from an excel file which has 8 sheets with one of the sheet containing 56000 lines. This sheet has 44 columns with data. In order to access data from first 2 rows using OpenXML, I am using following code.

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(importFileCopyPath, false))

{

string relationshipId = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(p => p.Name.Value == "Sheet1").Select(q => q.Id.Value).FirstOrDefault(); 

var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);

Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;

var sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

var rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();
}
```

Then I traverse through the rows collection I get in line number 5. Unfortunately for a file with 56000 lines this takes 2 minutes to extract data from first 2 rows. This is because line no. 3 loads the entire sheet with 56000 lines into the memory. 
Is there a better way to bypass loading entire sheet data and directly access contents from the first 2 rows?

Comment: Use SAX https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for the link. I tried SAX approach for making it faster but I don't get the required data from the cells. What I get is some decimal numbers which are not there in the excel sheet. Is there further customisation required in the code given for SAX in the sample link you have provided? . Also with the approach suggested in SAX how do you identify end of line and that new row has started?